# Web3J: TypeError: MyContract is not a constructor

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment

I am simply trying to call my contracts on a private blockchain from a nodeJS app after a call from the browser but I keep getting this error in my node:

```
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782560+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: MyContract is not a constructor
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782562+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/app.js:77:30
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782563+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782563+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782567+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/node_modules/express-stormpath/lib/middleware/authentication-required.js:25:12)
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782567+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express-stormpath/lib/middleware/get-user.js:154:11
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782568+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express-stormpath/lib/helpers/expand-account.js:145:5
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782568+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3694:9
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782569+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:359:16
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782569+00:00 app[web.1]:     at iteratorCallback (/app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:935:13)
2017-03-01T21:07:34.782570+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:843:16
```

Here is how i call my contract, what am I doing wrong ?

```
app.post('/api/getOrganisationDetails', stormpath.authenticationRequired, function(req, res){
    var rawString = req.user.customData;
    var stringJson = JSON.stringify(rawString);
    var customData = JSON.parse(stringJson);
    var web3 = new Web3();

    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(customData.ethereum_provider));
    var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
    var balance = web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase);

    var name = req.body.name;
    var ABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[],
            "name":"get",
            "outputs":[{"name":"","type":"int8"}],
            "type":"function"}];

    // creation of contract object
    var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
    var myContractInstance = new MyContract('0x90eb73c0bb07b0a5428b3d3ac2a5b7461bdd038b');
    var result = myContractInstance.get(name);
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200);
    res.end("hello world");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var myContractInstance =
    new MyContract('0x90eb73c0bb07b0a5428b3d3ac2a5b7461bdd038b');
```

you should have

```
var myContractInstance =
    MyContract.new({from:<fromAddr>, data:<compiledContractCode>, gas:<value>});
```

For example:

```
var myContractInstance =
    MyContract.new({from:'0xbc4773626fed4d763e5d02e3aaef85be6ec67994',
                    data:'0x... <compiledCode in hex> ...', gas:1000000});
```

Also, a simple way to get the ABI and compiled code for the above call is as follows (where `MyContractSource` is your Solidity code as a string, and the field name under `MyContractCompiled` - which has `info` and `code` sub-fields is the name of your contract in the Solidity source):

```
var MyContractCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(MyContractSource);
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(MyContractCompiled.MyContract.info.abiDefinition);
var myContractInstance =
    MyContract.new({from:'0xbc4773626fed4d763e5d02e3aaef85be6ec67994',
           data:MyContractCompiled.MyContract.code, gas:1000000});
```